# Rails 4 : How to disable the Edit, Destroy etc,

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can I disable the "Edit" and "Destory" in the Rails ?for example, if I want to disable the "Edit" for everyone,what show I do in the test_controller.rb ? or anything else? 
I am new to Rails, thanks in advance!

```
  class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update,:destroy ]

  # GET /books
  # GET /books.json
  def index
    @books = Book.all
  end

  # GET /books/1
  # GET /books/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /books/new
  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end

  # GET /books/1/edit
def edit
end

  # POST /books
  # POST /books.json

  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.save
        format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @book }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
   end


  # PATCH/PUT /books/1
  # PATCH/PUT /books/1.json

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.update(book_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @book }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /books/1
  # DELETE /books/1.json
  def destroy
    @book.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to books_url, notice: 'Book was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_book
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:name, :author, :price)
    end
end
```

---

```
`Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :books

  root :to => "home#index"
  get 'home/index'
end`
```

Comment: Please post your `test_controller.rb` and related routes in `routes.rb`

Comment: I am a bit confused. In your question you have mentioned `test_controller.rb` and you have posted content of 'books_controller.rb'. Do you want to make `edit` and `destroy` actions of `books_controller` inaccessible to everyone?

Comment: yes, so sorry to my change. `book` stands for `test`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can restrict the restful routes to make `edit` and `destroy` actions inaccessible.

In your routes.rb,

```
resources :books, except: [:edit, :destroy]
```

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created

---

**EDIT**

If you want to keep to the RESTful routes (so that you don't have to modify code in your views), you can use before_action in controller to redirect users.

```
before_action :redirect_user, only: [:edit,:destroy]

def redirect_user
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

This approach is generally used when you want to restrict access to certain actions based on some condition.

For example, if you want only admins to edit and remove books, you can have condition inside `redirect_user` that checks if current user is admin or not and redirects non-admin users.

Comment: thank you, it works! :)  but I have to manually remove some codes which contains `"Edit"` in the `/view/index.html.erb` or `show.html.erb`:(

Comment: See the edit. It's unusual that you want to keep the code but don't want anyone to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You should look in to the cancancan gem.
https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

It's an authorization library for Ruby on Rails which restricts what resources a given user is allowed to access. So you can create an admin class, and only allow administrators to edit and destroy. Its pretty simple to use and works well with devise.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I am gonna to look in the cancancan gem. :)