# Rails disable edit update delete routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to find a way to disable  resource routes like edit destroy and update. It can be done using this answer. [Disable Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202820/rails-4-how-to-disable-the-edit-destroy-etc) In this answer I can put code like this:

```
resources :books, except: [:edit, :destroy]
```

And it will work but I have a unique problem I have created many resource routes and my route file is like this:

```
         resources :expenditure_management2s do 
                            collection { post :import }
                            collection { get :dropdown }
                            collection { get :test }
                            end 
        resources :expenditure_management1s do 
                            collection { post :import }
                            collection { get :dropdown }
                            collection { get :test }
                            end 
        resources :expenditure_managements do 
                            collection { post :import }
                            collection { get :dropdown }
                            collection { get :test }
                            end 
                 ......
```

I have almost 100 routes like this If I have to change these methods one by one it would be a tough task. Is there any way where I can group these route into some method and reject edit update and destroy for all resource route.

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: Visual Code editor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can you use a scope in your `routes.rb` file like this:

```
scope except: [:edit, :destroy] do
  resources :users
end
```

Will return the routes:

```
users     GET   /users(.:format)   users#index
          POST  /users(.:format)   users#create
new_user  GET   /users/new(.:format)   users#new
user      GET   /users/:id(.:format)   users#show
          PATCH /users/:id(.:format)   users#update
          PUT   /users/:id(.:format)   users#update
```

As you can see the `users#destroy` and `users#edit` routes are missing.

**In your case, it would be:**

```
 scope except: [:edit, :destroy] do
    resources :expenditure_management2s do 
                        collection { post :import }
                        collection { get :dropdown }
                        collection { get :test }
                        end 
    resources :expenditure_management1s do 
                        collection { post :import }
                        collection { get :dropdown }
                        collection { get :test }
                        end 
    resources :expenditure_managements do 
                        collection { post :import }
                        collection { get :dropdown }
                        collection { get :test }
                        end 
 end
```